# Installing glibc 2.3 for mysql server

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, mysql, glibc

I need to install mysql server and client for a project of mine so I downloaded the MySQL-client-5.1.61-1.glibc23.i386.rpm for the client and MySQL-server-5.1.61-1.glibc23.i386.rpm for the server.
I followed the instructions on the mysql site and it says I need the glibc 2.3 libraries and what I try to install it gives me among other: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by MySQL-client-5.1.61-1.glibc23.i386

I didn't find a way to install it online and I don't really know how to build/compile it myself..

What to do? How do I easily install glibc 2.3?

*using Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that (nor you should use RPM packages in a Debian-based distribution like Ubuntu).

Just install the packages `mysql-client` and `mysql-server`, which already should be available in Ubuntu's repositories.